# The change of length of positive column in glow discharge

Tags: electricity, plasma-physics

When I was doing the experiment of glow discharge, I lowered the voltage between electrodes and find that the length of positive column will increased quickly around a certain voltage(the interval of change is less than 3 volts),  and I do not know why.
The gas used is air, the pressure is around 50Pa, the distance between electrodes is about 10cm. [image: The positive column when U=676V][image: The positive column when U=674V]

Comment: What's the potential difference between the electrodes?

Comment: At the point of change, the voltage is 676V to 674V.